# 404 error while trying to post using django tasty pie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

This is my api.py

```
# myapp/api.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource, ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
from links.models import Link


class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'users'
        excludes = ['email', 'password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        allowed_methods = ['post','get']
        fields = ['username']

        def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
            try:
                bundle = super(CreateUserResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, **kwargs)
                bundle.obj.set_password(bundle.data.get('password'))
                bundle.obj.save() 
            except IntegrityError:
                raise BadRequest('That username already exists')
            return bundle
```

Typed that on a python shell:

```
  r = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/api/users/username=Puck")
```

And got 404 as error response. How do I go about creating a new user using post?

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from links.api import LinkResource
from links.api import UserResource
from tastypie.api import Api
# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(UserResource())
v1_api.register(LinkResource())




urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:


    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     (r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
)
```

url schema:

```
^admin/
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/$ [name='api_v1_top_level']
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>link)/$ [name='api_dispatch_list']
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>link)/schema/$ [name='api_get_schema']
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>link)/set/(?P<pk_list>\w[\w/;-]*)/$ [name='api_get_multiple']
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>link)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/$ [name='api_dispatch_detail']
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>users)/$ [name='api_dispatch_list']
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>users)/schema/$ [name='api_get_schema']
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>users)/set/(?P<pk_list>\w[\w/;-]*)/$ [name='api_get_multiple']
^api/ ^(?P<api_name>v1)/ ^(?P<resource_name>users)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/$ [name='api_dispatch_detail']
The current URL, api/v1/users/username=Puck, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: What did you put in `urls.py` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you want to access is:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/?username=Puck
```

since you declared `api_name='v1'`.

Comment: Nope. Still the same error. I've actually tried all the possible permutations/combinations and it is still giving me the same error.